# Adding a line break between imported images from excel into outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

Below code works fine (I just need to add some more code to close the files again), but now my 2 images are pasted next to each other, I would like to get them below each other, but how ?

I would like a blank link between **rng1** and **rng2**

```
Sub CopyRngToOutlook2()
Dim doc As Object, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="V:\CUSTOMER SERVICE\06. PERFORMANCE BOARD\Performance 
Board BIDI BELUX-V7.xlsx").Sheets("Hoofdscherm").Range("B3:F23")
Set rng2 = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="V:\SUPPLY CHAIN TEAM\08. 
STOCKOPVOLGING\AnalyseVolledigeStock2023-2024.xlsm").Sheets("Ordermix Oude 
stock").Range("D2:G23")

With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
    .Display
    Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
    
    rng1.CopyPicture
    doc.Range(0, 0).Paste
    
    rng2.CopyPicture
    doc.Range(0, 0).Paste
    
    .To = "someone@somewhere.com"
    .Subject = "Send Email Body"
    '.send
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the following code after pasting the first image:

```
doc.Range(0, 0).InsertAfter Chr(11) 'Chr(11) is a line break in Word
```